# Java Interface Testing and Coding Issues

Tags: java, arrays

I have been working on this assignment for the past few hours and I'm stuck on the last method Histogram required for the assignment, I have problems with testing and the code probably (I'm using NetBeans).

the method should do this >
**histogram**: Takes a positive number n indicating the number of divisions in which
the span of the data is divided, and returns an array of integers of length n, where
each element of the array contains the count of the elements that fall into this
division. For example, if the data is (0.5, 1.2, 2.4, 9.8, 5.1, 10.5), then its span is
10.0 (from 0.5 to 10.5). histogram(4) would divide this range into four segments:
0.5—3.0, 3.0—5.5, 5.5—8.0, and 8.0—10.5. Inspecting the data, we see that 3 values
fall in the first segment, 1 value in the second, 0 values in the third, and 2 values
in the fourth. Therefore, the returned value is an array of length 4 containing the
values (3, 1, 0, 2) in that order.
Note that the sum of the elements in the returned array is equal to the number of
elements in the data array.

here is the code:

```
  @Override     
  public int[] histogram(int divisions) {       
    int[] wide = new int[divisions];        
    double segment = span() / divisions;        
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {     
      if (data[i] <= (smallestElement() + segment)) {   
        wide[0] = wide[0]+ 1;   
      } else if (data[i] <= (smallestElement() + (2 * segment))) {      
        wide[1] = wide[1]+ 1;   
      } else if (data[i] <= (smallestElement() + (3 * segment))) {      
        wide[2] = wide[2]+ 1;   
      } else if (data[i] <= (smallestElement() + (4 * segment))) {
        wide[3] = wide[3]+ 1;       
      }     
    }       
    return wide;        
  }
```

and here is the test of the method above:

```
   @Test        
   public void testHistogram() {        
     double[] data = new double[3];     
     data = new double[]{0.5, 1.2, 2.4, 9.8, 5.1, 10.5};        
     int[] data2 = new int[4];      
     data2 = new int[]{3, 1, 0, 2};     
     DoubleArrayStatisticalOutcomes a = new DoubleArrayStatisticalOutcomes(data);       
     assertArrayEquals(data2, a.histogram(4));      
   }
```

I use WebCat to submit my work, and when I submit the assignment it tells me that there's some tests missing for the method plus this "histogram is not accounting for the correct number of elements", my question is does the issue occur in the coding itself or am i missing something, same with the test.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think interpreting the messages you receive after submitting your work must be part of the assignment. "There's some tests missing" could mean you're not [covering all your code with tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage). The other message should be self explanatory!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re only testing your method with the values from the example. The problem is that you probably wrote the method with this particular example in mind. What will happen if you try to make a histogram with a different length?

You should write more tests with different data and different parameters, and check that they all pass.